# How to get the file_name in C++ if I executed my program with ./program_name<file_name

Tags: c++

if I was executing the program like this: ./program_name<file_name
How would I get the file_name in c++.

I tried to use argue[1] in the main and open file eg.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1],ios::in);
}
```

its not opening

Comment: `argv[1]` should work. Show us a snippet that reproduces your cas.e

Comment: Also, what do you think `./blabla < blablabla` does?? I am sure you want `./blabla blablabla`

Comment: Can't be done. But the real question is why do you want to? The whole point of `./aaa < bbb` is that the operating system will open `bbb` for you. If you want to open `bbb` yourself then use `./aaa bbb` and the code above should work.

Comment: Off topic, but `std::ifstream` already has `ios::in` set. There is no point in specifycing the direction for `ifstream` and `ofstream`.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 operator system should open the txt and I can just carry on

Comment: This is what I don't like about programming. So many arguments.

Comment: @user4581301 that is what I like about programming. So many arguments :D

Answer (score 0):

The `<` operator `cat` the file in input and you try in your code to get it from parameter. If you want to use input:

```cpp
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string data;
    // here you read all the file
    std::getline(std::cin, data);
}
```